# Deploy Pyramid App on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pyramid

I'm attempting to deploy my Pyramid Application on AWS via Elastic Beanstalk. The upload/deploy works fine but when I send a request to the application I'm met with the following error:

`File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 839, in resolve
[Sat Jul 16 21:04:40.351021 2016] [:error] [pid 10837] [remote 76.202.70.172:28102]     raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
[Sat Jul 16 21:04:40.351110 2016] [:error] [pid 10837] [remote 76.202.70.172:28102] pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'MyAppName' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[Sat Jul 16 21:34:47.346311 2016] [:error] [pid 10837] [remote 76.202.70.172:28102] mod_wsgi (pid=10837): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.`

...where "MyAppName" is the name of *my* application (aka the one I've developed and am attempting to use).

From what it looks like, my actual application is not installed during the app deployment. Typically, on a local machine, after developing the application you run:

`pip install -e .`

in order to install the actual application you are developing. I suppose my question, although it seems silly, is: How do I actually install the application I've written onto the ec2 instance during the upload/deploy process of Elastic Beanstalk? Is there something that should be included in requirements.txt to also install the application in which the requirements.txt exists? Is this done automatically? What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you try "sudo pip install --upgrade setup tools" on your EC2 instance and then try to install the app.

Comment: @error2007s Sure. What exactly will upgrading setuptools do? I was hoping for a solution that's already integrated into the chain of event that occurs as a result of using Elastic Beanstalk GUI's upload/deploy button. For example, I'm using a .ebextensions directory and several additional config files to further configure the servers upon environment creation. I was hoping to not have to SSH into the instances and manually configure them each time. Is there a way to locally include the project itself in requirements.txt?

Comment: I am guessing it is a version conflict you will not have to do that each time. EB CLI Throws Exceptions VersionConflict.

Comment: @error2007s Same problem after updating setuptools.

Comment: For the solution, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426276/deploy-pyramid-application-on-elastic-beanstalk][1]