# Deploy Pyramid Application on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pyramid

Does anyone have experience installing a `Pyramid` application via `Elastic Beanstalk`? My application deploys but I cannot configure the application's `application.py` (or `pyramid.wsgi`) file to work properly. Within `get_app` the following error occurs:

```
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
[Sun Jul 17 21:24:15.482379 2016] [:error] [pid 736] [remote 127.0.0.1:9522]     raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
[Sun Jul 17 21:24:15.482427 2016] [:error] [pid 736] [remote 127.0.0.1:9522] DistributionNotFound: The 'MyApp' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Where `MyApp` is the application I am trying to run.

Here is my `application.py`:

```
from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
import os, site, sys
ini_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'production.ini')
setup_logging(ini_path)
application = get_app(ini_path, 'main')
```

It seems as though the error occurs because its looking for `MyApp` within `/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` rather than `/opt/current/python/app/`. What am I missing? Do I need to add something to my path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a friend over on the "pylons-discuss" Google groups forum I now have a solution that works.

You will need to add a config command for your environment that runs the `setup.py develop` command. To do this, you will need to add a file to your .ebextensions folder named packages.config (or use whatever naming scheme you like) with the following:

```
container_commands:
  01_setup:
    command: "/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python setup.py develop"
```

Alternatively, you can (and probably should) run:

```
container_commands:
  01_setup:
    command: "/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -e ."
```

(Although I would like someone to verify this, just to be sure.)

Next, run the `eb deploy` command. Elastic Beanstalk should now recognize that your package is installed. Cheers!

*To understand the difference between the previous two solutions see:*

[Python setup.py develop vs install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048732/python-setup-py-develop-vs-install][1])